# Grails spring security defaultTargetUrl going wrong path

Tags: spring, grails

Grails 2.4 with Spring security 2 3RC

I have this on my Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/home/index"
```

But this keeping me redirecting to

```
assets/favicon.ico
```

And my HomeController is like that

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
def index() {
    if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        redirect controller: 'admin', action: 'index'
        return
    }
}
```

And I modify this in my UrlMapping:

```
"/"(controller: 'home', action:'index')
```

Why it keeps me sending wrong path?

Update: using another computer, it redirects me to /asset/grails_logo.png

Comment: Please try to search in your project by keyword "favicon" (maybe including plugins) and look for all actions.
Maybe some other action redirects you.
Also you may try to disable Security plugin, it may helps you to locate where the trouble.

Comment: If I disable the plugin security, it goes the right path, and it's a clean project, just followed by grails tutorial. So there are no actions.

Comment: Could you share this project for me?
I want to watch it by myself.

Comment: I don't know if there's wrong with the grails version and spring security, I'm using grails 2.4 and spring security 2.0-RC or 3.0-RC(must check). And pm your email so I can send to you

Comment: Couldn't find how to send pms here.
Please contact me at google.com/+DmitriyAleshkowsky

Comment: Can you open a browser to http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/assets/favicon.ico in development mode?

Comment: yes, but it says that I have no permission to see it.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I am having the same issue

Comment: Never mind.. The below answer worked... You haven't approved it yet.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are having a similar problem to the one I experienced upgrading a Grails 1.x application to 2.4.2.  When you attempt to access a URL/page that is protected by Spring Security authorization rules and you are not logged in, it redirects you to the login page.  Upon successful login, it redirects you to the URL you requested.  In this case, your favicon.ico and grails_logo.png are being protected by authorization rules, unintentionally I'm guessing, so it redirects you to the login page.  Upon successful login, it redirects you to the favicon.ico or grails_logo.png URL because that is protected URL that was being requested when authorization failed. Change your authorization rules accordingly (may want to do both if you have assets in both locations):

If you are using the **Asset Pipeline** Plugin, use:

```
'/assets/**':     ['permitAll']
```

If you are using something like the **Resources** Plugin, use:

```
'/css/**':     ['permitAll'],
'/js/**':      ['permitAll'],
'/images/**':  ['permitAll']
```

Comment: Accidentally copied the paths from the Resources example into the asset pipeline example.  All assets from the asset-pipeline are served directly from /assets URL, so `/assets/app.js` and `/assets/app.css`